# Deprecated getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on HTTP calls. How can I fix it without switching to https?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps on my webpage and on localhost everything works fine. But when I uploaded my webpage to amazon aws, I'm getting the error:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure
>   origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should
>   consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.
>   See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

I've read that the solution for it is to use https instead of http, but my question is - how can I achieve a working version while using amazon aws? Can I just turn on there the https?

Answer (score 0):

Just switch your site to https:

AWS provide free certificates https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/